# Is there a term that covers advantages and disadvantages?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term that refers to both advantages and disadvantages?  I'm trying to find a succinct name for a section of a report that summarises advantages and disadvantages of a particular product.

Comment: "factors" or "factors for consideration"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider [consequences](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/consequence) or [effects](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/effect) or even [results](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/result).

Answer (score 3):

"Relative merits". *Merits* means the advantages, but the phrase "relative merits" is common and suggests a weighing up that would include disadvantages.

Comment: Wouldn't that imply a section comparing, say, the relative merits of two products rather than the good and bad points or a single product?

Comment: Yes, for me too, relative merits means comparing two products, not comparing how good or bad a merit is.

Comment: You're either comparing 2 or more products, or comparing it with the possibility of just not buying it and keeping the money, or comparing 2 or more products **and** the possibility of forgoing them all.